# Is the Power series convergent at $|t|=1$?

Tags: power-series

$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\prod\limits_{j=1}^{k}\frac{4j^2-6j+3}{2j(2j+1)}t^{2k+1}$$ I could prove using ratio test that if $|t|<1$ this above series converges. But wolfram alpha shows when $|t|=1$ this series still converges. I am stuck here. Ratio test is inconclusive. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like a job for [Raabe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test#Raabe.27s_test).

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks I will try this beautiful test. Intriguingly wolfram alpha says "by comparison test" this converges when $|t|=1$. I am still searching for a series which dominates this .

Comment: $$\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^2}$$ dominates it, for example.

Comment: Im sorry sir.. I cant see..:(

Comment: Comes out of Raabe's test. We have $\frac{a_k}{a_{k-1}} = 1 - \frac{2}{k} + O(k^{-2})$, hence the sequence $a_k$ behaves asymptotically like $\frac{c}{k^2}$.

Comment: I applied raabe's test and found that $k(\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}-1)\to 2$ as $k\to\infty$. Therefore the series converges. But could not understand your argument. How $a_k=\mathcal{O}(1/k^2)$?

Comment: Take logarithms. $\log \frac{a_k}{a_{k-1}} = - \frac{2}{k} + O(k^{-2})$, so summing that up yields $\log a_k - \log a_1 = -2\log k + O(1)$, and hence $a_k = \frac{a_1}{k^2}\cdot e^{O(1)}$.

Comment: Fantastic argument Sir. Many thanks..:)

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

For $|t|=1$, take logarithm of the product and find an equivalent to $$\ln (  \frac {4j^2-6j+3}{2j (2j+1)} )=$$
$$\ln (1+\frac {-8j+3}{2j (2j+1)}  )$$
using

$$\ln (1+X)\sim X \;\;(X\to 0) $$

Comment: Please read the question properly. I know radius of convergence is 1 but when $t=1$ I need to show that the series converges.

Comment: Can i know why this downvote.

Comment: @mudok Please read your title asking for the radius .

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima that's why the question has a body; the downvote is justified as your post answers a different question than the one asked by the OP

Comment: @Victor The OP should change the title.